# JQuery trigger("input") doesn't update Polymer data binding model

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I manually set the variable and call event:

```
text.val( newVal );
text.trigger("input");
```

And I have data binding:

```
<div>[[val]]</div>
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="avatar url" value="{{val::input}}" />
```

When I set new value text.val( newVal ), `<div>[[val]]</div>` doesn't get new value.

Comment: If you trigger `change`?

Comment: I tried. It does not work.